# Cannot use SDP in Debian Squeezy

Tags: debian-squeeze, infiniband, mellanox

I have severe problems running SDP on Debian Squeeze. I'm using two machines with Mellanox adapters each. My /etc/modules looks like this:

```
mlx4_ib
# Mellanox ConnectX cards
#ib_mthca # some mellanox cards
#iw_cxgb3 # Chelsio T3 cards
#iw_nes # NetEffect cards
#
# Protocol modules
# Common modules
rdma_ucm
ib_umad
ib_uverbs
# IP over IB
ib_ipoib
# scsi over IB
ib_srp
# IB SDP protocol
ib_sdp
```

Nevertheless, ib_sdp cannot be loaded:

```
modprobe ib_sdp
FATAL: Module ib_sdp not found.
```

Thus, all applications which I want to test running via SDP are throwing errors. NPtcp for example:

```
LD_PRELOAD=libsdp.so NPtcp 
NetPIPE: can't open stream socket! errno=97
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

SDP is considered obsolete. Its successor is called rsockets and is included in the latest version of librdmacm. More information can be found here:

- http://www.openfabrics.org/ofa-documents/doc_download/495-rsockets.html
- http://git.openfabrics.org/git?p=~shefty/librdmacm.git